# python str.contains with double quotation

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe with string columns. I need to find string which includes double quotation but I don't know how to find `"toString": "Ready"` :

```
df1['column2'] = np.where(df1["column1"].str.contains(""toString": "Ready""), 'abc', 'def')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `'` as terminators to be able to use literal `"` as follows:

```
df1['column2'] = np.where(df1["column1"].str.contains('"toString": "Ready"'), 'abc', 'def')
```

or do escape `"` if you must use `"` as terminators:

```
df1['column2'] = np.where(df1["column1"].str.contains("\"toString\": \"Ready\""), 'abc', 'def')
```

Note that first is more readable, but need to escape `"` might arise if you need to use literal `"` and literal `'` in 1 `str`.

Comment: it doesn't work. Maybe blank space should be also replaced?

Comment: I deleted blank space and it works, thanks !